# Clean implementation for multiple decisions in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**background**

I'm writing an API that processes data from an external application. My application processes JSON responses from the external application and offers relevant information to consumers of my service. (These consumers are internal to my organisation)

The external application has an API that allows me to check for updates. Updates are triggered by events. The API offers 12 different types of events. The event types are offered in a string format. (ex. 'MoveEvent', 'DeleteEvent', 'CreateEvent')

I need to write a specific processing algorithm for each event.

**Problem**

I'm looking for a clean, DRY and SOLID way to implement the event processing system. The focus for this application is on code quality and a solid architecture.

**My solution and thoughts**

There are a number of ways to tackle this issue, but my best guess so far has been:

- Create a hash that holds the string name of the event types and map them to a processing class.
- Use the Strategy pattern to define a common interface for all the processing classes to adhere to, so that any mediating class only needs to know the message to which the processing classes can respond.
- Use some sort of factory (method) to instantiate a concrete implementation.

I'm explicitly looking to ignore a long if-elsif-else solution, unless someone can convince me to do otherwise.

Suggestions and criticism is always welcome, thanks!

Comment: Are all the event so different that it would be justify having a different class for each event?

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII It seems so. The external API uses events for a broad brush of triggers. 


Some event triggers only return a small object, whilst some return the entire data set that is available for a given object. (Which can get as big as +4000 lines of JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this type of situation, I like to use this pattern:

```
class Processor

  class << self
    def for(name, data)
      processors[name].new(data)
    end

    def processors
      {
        'MoveEvent' => MoveEventProcessor, 
        'DeleteEvent' => DeleteEventProcessor, 
        'CreateEvent' => CreateEventProcessor
      }
    end

  end

  attr_reader :data
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  class MoveEventProcessor < Processor
    #... code to handle this event
  end

  class DeleteEventProcessor < Processor
    #... code to handle this event
  end

  class CreateEventProcessor < Processor
    #... code to handle this event
  end

end

p Processor.for 'MoveEvent', {some: :data}
```

Comment: I really like this one. 

It's close to what I would've done, except that I would've added an execute method to all of the subclasses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So my suggestion would be to not over engineer this chances are that you will have to iteratively refactor or reimplement your solution as you become aware of things. I think the first Idea you came up with is probably the most straight forward way to go about it. Even if you want to house that hash inside of a class that then handles and required processing of the selected event class that would still seem reasonable (so basically number 2). ReggieB's answers is about what I would expect.

Comment: A small note; I probably wrote it in a misleading way, but the 3 points I defined were meant as one solution in its entirety. 

I really like ReggieB's solution and will probably take that route.

Thanks :)